# A PhoneGap app on Android tries to fetch external resources from cache

Tags: android, cordova

I'm working on a PhoneGap application which should fetch date from a remote server. This works well if I compile the Android app manually. But if I compile using build.phonegap.com, the all external requests hit the cache which responds with 404.

[image]

config.xml contains:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you edit your config.xml in your staging foler

[image]

Comment: It was fixed by replacing the app ID "com.phonegap.helloworld" with a real ID.